# Total Amount vs. Percentage of Nutrients

Tags: nutrition, diet

Does ingesting (for example) 30 grams of sugar with one litre of water a day has the same effect on the dietary intake as ingesting 60 grams of sugar with two litres of water? How does the absorption of nutrients looks like your body?

Comment: In theory, it shouldn't matter where you get your macros from as long as you get them. In theory it shouldn't even matter where you get your calories from. You could eat McDonalds every day and as long as you keep your calorie count in a deficit you'd still lose weight - but you'll feel lethargic and generally crappy all the time

Comment: I do not understand your questions. I suggest asking a native English speaker to help you rewrite them.

Comment: Are you asking if the volume you eat is irrelevant and all that matters is the concentration of nutrients in the food or drink?

Comment: If you ingest 30kg of sugar with 1000 litres of water you will surely die.

Comment: @kingW3 There is indeed a limit to the question.

Comment: @KateGregory Yes. Additional clarification:  I'm thinking in terms of deposition and ''flow'', just like a river carries its sediments. Heaped up nutrients in your body would not be good thing, right? So you need an extra amount of water to ''keep the flow going''. For instance, people have a higher blood pressure because the blood flow does not keep going and nutrients start to heap up in the veins. I think that if these people would have drink more water, the nutrients would spread more evenly in the water and the extra water would cause less stacking.